# webdriver - how to list all and click the href one by one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can i list out all **title="Race 1"**, **"Race 2",** **"Race 3"** then using python from the folllwing HTML

```
driver.find_element_by_name('title=Race1').click()
```

And then Click one by one, that mean total click 3 time. first click **"Race 1"** , second click **"Race 2"** and third click **"Race 3"** , thanks !

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="padding-right:3px;">Race</td>
<td class="raceButton" style="PADDING-LEFT:3px"><a href="/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=EN&amp;date=06-06-2018&amp;venue=HV&amp;raceno=1" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('race_num_1', '', '/racing/info/images/num_1_on.gif?CV=L209R1d',1);"><img id="raceSelBtn1" src="/racing/info/images/num_1_on.gif?CV=L209R1d" border="0" title="Race 1"></a></td>
<td class="raceButton" style="PADDING-LEFT:3px"><a href="/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=EN&amp;date=06-06-2018&amp;venue=HV&amp;raceno=2" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('race_num_2', '', '/racing/info/images/num_2_on.gif?CV=L209R1d',1);"><img id="raceSelBtn2" src="/racing/info/images/num_2.gif?CV=L209R1d" border="0" title="Race 2"></a></td>
<td class="raceButton" style="PADDING-LEFT:3px"><a href="/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=EN&amp;date=06-06-2018&amp;venue=HV&amp;raceno=3" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('race_num_3', '', '/racing/info/images/num_3_on.gif?CV=L209R1d',1);"><img id="raceSelBtn3" src="/racing/info/images/num_3.gif?CV=L209R1d" border="0" title="Race 3"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
It seems that the elements you're trying to click on are `img`. So if you want to find the link itself you can try to get images parents (by xpath).

You can do something like this:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    img_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('raceSelBtn{}'.format(i))
    btn_link = img_btn.find_element_by_xpath('..') # Get img parent, the link
    btn_link.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

`<img id="raceSelBtn1" src="/racing/info/images/num_1_on.gif?CV=L209R1d" border="0" title="Race 1">`

`driver.find_element_by_name('title=Race1').click()` wont work because the node that you want has no name attribute!

One of the way you can access the above node by `find_element_by_id('raceSelBtn1`)`

But since you want a list of webelements you will have to use `find_elements_by_xpath()` method(plural). When you use `find_elements_by_xxx` it returns you a list of webelements which match your given location strategy. You can then loop over this list to perform actions over individual elements.

**Try the following code snippet.**

```
buttons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@title, 'Race')]")
for button in buttons_list:
    button.click()
```

Comment: Read more about location strategies here --> http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html